# How can I shorten the navigation breadcrumbs to just link to the last page in Moodle 2.5.3?

Tags: moodle

I need to change the breadcrumbs navigation in Moodle 2.5.3 to just show a link to the last page in the hierarchy.  How can I do this?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme you should [override the core renderer](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer) and in particular the the navbar() function.

It is unclear what you mean by last page - the last page a user came from or the last link in the generated trail.

The latter case is easier so I'll deal with that first - you can use something like the following taken from [here](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=184179#p1049308):

```
/*
 * This renders the navbar.
 * Uses bootstrap compatible html.
 */
public function navbar() {
    $is_course = false;
    $items = $this->page->navbar->get_items();

    //If this is a course, only output the course node and the last link node (if any)
    //       (e.g. $item->action is not null)
    foreach ($items as $item) {
            if (!$is_course) {
                    $is_course = (navigation_node::TYPE_COURSE == $item->type);
            }
    }

    if ($is_course) {
            //Only output some nodes
            $last_node_found = false;
            $items = array_reverse($items);

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                    //Only output crumbs with links
                    if (navigation_node::TYPE_COURSE == $item->type ||
                            (!$last_node_found && $item->action)) {
                            $last_node_found = true;
                            $item->hideicon = true;
                            $breadcrumbs[] = $this->render($item);
                    }

                    if (navigation_node::TYPE_COURSE == $item->type) {
                            //We're done here
                            break;
                    }
            }

            $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
    }
    else {
            //Output all navigation nodes
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $item->hideicon = true;
                    $breadcrumbs[] = $this->render($item);
            }
    }
    $divider = '<span class="divider">/</span>';
    $list_items = '<li>'.join(" $divider</li><li>", $breadcrumbs).'</li>';
    $title = '<span class="accesshide">'.get_string('pagepath').'</span>';
    return $title . "<ul class=\"breadcrumb\">$list_items</ul>";
}
```

Basically given the list of items this is reversed and then each items tested for whether it is a link and its type. The others are ignored.

In the former case you could use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for a link or you would need write to information to the session to get the URL and name of page if that doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve this with css. Something like:

```
.breadcrumb li {
    display: none;
    /* other css code */
}

.breadcrumb li:last-child {
    display: block;
}
```